# selenium to read text contained in tile image and click on a button

Tags: c#, selenium

I have a web page with contents like tile images which includes some text content and an image in it. In my application user will enter a text in a text box. What I want to do using selenium is that I want the text to be read somehow which is displayed in that tile image and if it match with the user entered text then I need to click on the button displayed below.

Since I dont have enough reputation, I can't post a sample pic showing how the tile and button look like.Sorry..

The tile image text has got same "classname" for all tile images and the button has got unique id's. But since I cant predict user entered text, I cant use ID in my application.

For your understanding, I am posting html code for both.

HTML Code for tile image text:

```
<span class="rm-displayBlock rm-marginBottom5px rm-fontWeightBold largeTileTitle rm-textOverflowEllipsed">10monkeys.com Maths (FULL)</span>
```

HTML Code for Button:

```
<a href="JavaScript:;" appid="f03a1962-38fc-e1f5-cee1-a8a9ce4684a5" id="d70e5839-a9cd-b86f-cba5-3c41cd0826fe" class="btn btn-primary rm-floatLeft">Buy</a>
```

How can I achieve What I said? Any comments would be really appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

There has to be some kind of correlation between the text and the button.Then you can get the element using the driver.find_element_by_name(or something similar in java) based on this text and say driver.click() to click the button.